# Animated Gif in Gwt

Tags: gwt

I am wanting to use a amimated gif in gwt and remove it from the dom after it plays.

My thinking is to use a timer object then remove it after x amount of time.Is this the correct or only way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image is a Widget. you can add it with simple add(Widget, int x, int y) method

```
    Image image = new Image(/*source*/);

    RootPanel.get().add(image, left, top)
```

or you can add it to the any panel or table

```
AbsolutePanel a = new AbsolutePanel();
a.add(image, left, top);
```

Comment: Thanks.Do you know about the removing it after it plays? Timer or other means

Comment: It is so simple panel.remove(widget) or panel.remove(index)

Comment: Thanks Again.I want to remove it after it plays through what is the best method.Set a timer when I add it then remove after the timer goes off.Or is there a better way.

Comment: maybe it is good to use gwt animation for your needs. have a look at this example http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwAnimation after it is finished you can remove. If the time is needed you should keem timer

Comment: Cool.I have thought of a method to use.Thanks this gwt animation should work.